# Facebook sharing of link using woobox not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm developing a facebook sharing link using on woobox for my fb page, I have created a facebook app to be able to use the sharing api of facebook but the problem is its not working here is how I used it

```
<a href="javascript:popup_share('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=MYIDREMOVED&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPageOfme',800,520)" title="Share on Facebook">
   <i id="fbshare" class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

it kept on displaying this error message
[image]
I'm struggling to finish this someone please help me I'm new also on fb apps am I doing something wrong here??

Comment: Have you first of all _researched_ that error message? You are absolutely not the first person to encounter it …

Comment: I have created a facebook app before and this error also came how I solved this was on the app domain I just added the domain of my site.., but this time I tried putting facebook's domain but an error occured saying its a facebook domain or something.. so there I was mind f***ed on how the hell do I solve this then..

Comment: `redirect_uri` has to point back to your own website (and that one you have to configure within your app settings), you are not allowed to redirect the user to your Facebook page after sharing.

Comment: ohh... it actually worked when I changed my redirect_uri into my site's main domain. Thanks for the help @Cbroe